# How do I avoid nil pointer evaluating resource.Resource.Permalink with Hugo static site generator using range .Pages?

Tags: hugo

I'm trying to create a schema for events within a range of pages.  This works fine for a single page but I'm trying to add on my list template so I have all the events.  I'm getting the following error currently: **nil pointer evaluating resource.Resource.Permalink**

```
    ....{{ define "JSON-LD" }}
    {{ range .Pages }}
<script type='application/ld+json'>
  {
    "@context": "https://www.schema.org",
    "@type": "Event",
    "name": "{{.Description}}",
    "url": "{{.Params.eventURL}}",
    {{ with .Params.images -}}
  "image": [
    {{- range $index, $element := . -}}
    {{- if ne $index 0 -}}, {{ end }}
    {{ $image := $.Resources.GetMatch $element -}}
    {{ $image.Permalink -}}
    {{- end }}
    ],
  {{ end -}}....
```

Answer (score 0):

That error is due to the Resources.GetMatch coming back nil and therefore their is a nil pointer when you try to get {{$image.Permalink}}

{{ with }} is a good option to check for success before you try to get the Permalink.

However, the error you describe is an error you probably want as it means you have a resource not found - i.e. $element is not a valid resource in that case, which you should fix in the markdown or wherever you are getting it from as then, you have no real, at build time, way to know you have an invalid resource.

I hope that helps.